# What does it mean: 'to have a run in'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is 'to have a run in' in this sentence:

> I was one of 5 white kids in my school growing up. Every black kid had a run in. I never did. Luck? My good behavior? Neither.

There is no much context, it is a part of [that twit](https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/1268722604304560128).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shortened version of "to have a run-in with the law."

Comment: A "run-in" need not be "with the law," it simply means a negative encounter: an altercation or quarrel between two parties. And this doesn't actually answer the question ("what does it **mean**?) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: After an edit to the question, the context is a tweet involving George Floyd. Given this, the use of *run-in* is specifically referring to police harassment.

[**run-in**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run%20in):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   2 : ALTERCATION, QUARREL

The narrator is saying that all of the black kids had a *run-in* with police, but that they, being white, never did. So, it's also describing racial discrimination.